# Looking for an e-commerce platform that also has appointment/calendar scheduling

Tags: looking-for-a-script, ecommerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

I am trying to find a solution that will allow me to manage both an e-commerce store for physical goods, as well as a calendar/appointment scheduler. I've been unable to find a single solution so far, but figured I would see if any of you have any leads on such a platform.

Comment: And I want a car that also knows how to make a good coffee. Sorry but I didn't really understand the connection between the two...

Answer (score 2):

I think [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) would suit your needs so long as you installed an appointment plugin, [see here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14973/P0/) for more information.